# How to use the result of one function as a parameter of a new function in python?

Tags: python, function, parameters

For example:

```
def title(a,b):
   ...
 
def movie( c = title, d):
     ...
```

But I get : NameError: name 'title' is not defined

How can I use function 'title' in function 'movie' ?

I have try:

```
def movie(title(a, b), c):
```

But SyntaxError: invalid syntax now.

Comment: You use it when you call the function: `movie(title('x', 'y') 'z')`

Comment: Are you expecting the _default value_ to be the result of calling `title`? With what arguments? Or are you expecting the function itself to be the default value, in which case what you've posted _does work_ (`title` _is_ defined, the problem is that you have a non-default argument following it - you certainly don't get `NameError: name 'title' is not defined`, so please give an actual [mre]).

Comment: The `title` function needs to return something useful.

Comment: Then why aren't you calling it? What would you call it _with_? Again give a [mre].

Comment: What do you mean by "use" the function "in" the other function? **Exactly what should happen** when the code runs, step by step? How do you want to use the code? Also, please read [ask] and [mre] and make sure (by trying it yourself) that someone else can **copy and paste** the code you show **without changing anything** and **directly** see the **exact** problem you describe. Code like in the first example cannot cause that `NameError`, and will cause a `SyntaxError` instead (it is not allowed to put a default argument before a non-default argument).

Comment: "Yes I expecting the default value to be the result of calling title" Of calling title **with what arguments**? Where is the data supposed to come from?

Answer (score 0):

```
def add(a, b):
    return a + b

def mult(c, d):
    return c * d

print(mult(add(2, 2), 3))
#          ^   ^  ^   ^
#          |   |  |   |
#function "c"=(a +b),*d

# (2 + 2) x 3 = 12
#  ^   ^    ^
#  |   |    |
#  a   b    d
```

Comment: Based on the comment discussion, this is not the question OP is trying to ask. However, please do not try to answer confusing or unclear questions. See [answer].

Comment: Please consider adding some explanation to the source code explaining how it solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

When you call the function in movie, also give it parameters (your a and b)
Like:

`movie(title(a, b), c)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Based on the comment discussion, this is not the question OP is trying to ask. However, please do not try to answer confusing or unclear questions. See [answer].